# "Enters the battlefield as a copy" and Thryx, the Sudden Storm

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I control [Shark Typhoon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShark%20Typhoon%5d) and [Thryx, the Sudden Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThryx%2c%20the%20Sudden%20Storm%5d). I decide to cast [Clever Impersonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClever%20Impersonator%5d) and want it to enter the battlefield as a copy of my Shark Typhoon. I'm trying to figure out answers to following questions:

1. What is the converted mana cost of Clever Impersonator? Can it be countered? What will be power and toughness of shark token created by Shark Typhoon?
2. Does Clever Impersonator cost one less to cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cast Clever Impersonator, it is still Clever Impersonator and has all the properties of Clever Impersonator, most notably here having CMC 4. It is only when the spell resolves and it enters the battlefield that you choose which nonland permanent it is going to copy and it takes on the characteristics of Shark Typhoon.

Therefore:

- Yes, it can be countered (because it has CMC 4)
- No shark token will be created because it's a creature spell.
- No, it still costs 2UU to cast.

Answer (score 1):

### While Clever Impersonator is on the stack, it is still itself

Clever Impersonator's ability is a replacement effect that changes how it enters the battlefield. That means that the choice of what it is impersonating and the change into a copy of that permanent happen while the spell is resolving, as it enters the battlefield.

Until that point, Clever Impersonator's attributes are the ones printed on the card.  It is a creature spell with a mana cost of 2UU, and as such it will not be effected by either Shark Typhoon (because it's a creature spell) or Thryx (because the CMC* is less than 5).

*Converted Mana Cost.